# Overriding with a stored property

Tags: swift, inheritance, overriding, member

I extended the `MKPointAnnotation` class this way:

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation{

    let eventID: Int
    let coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String? // error here
    let location:String

    init(eventID:Int, coords:CLLocationCoordinate2D, location:String, title:String?) {

        self.eventID = eventID
        self.coords = coords
        self.title = title
        self.location = location

        super.init()
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot override with a stored property 'title'
```

(I suppose I'd get the same error if I renamed the member `coords` to `coordinate`).

So, I tried the following:

```
private var _title:String?

override var title: String? {
        get { return _title }
        set { _title = newValue }
    }
```

but, as I add `self.title = title` in the body of the `init` I get:

```
'self' used in property access 'title' before 'super.init' call
```

If I move `super.init()` above, I get two kinds of error:

1. `Property 'self.eventID' not initialized at super.init call (1 error)`
2. `Immutable value 'self.coords' may only be initialized once (repeated for every property)`

What's the right way to declare the `title` property? Is there any possibility to override it? I found many questions about this topic, but no example with extending a built-in class. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @Scriptable: in fact, I started by adding the property to the instance but I didn't like it. I didn't know I could directly set their value after the init as suggested by farzadshbfn

Comment: Yeah I think that is the better solution myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to redeclare `var title: String?` again? by subclassing `MKPointAnnotation` you already have access to `title`. (same thing goes for `coords`).

You can just set title, after `super.init()`

```swift
init(eventID: Int, coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D, location: String, title: String?) {

        self.eventID = eventID
        self.coords = coords
        self.location = location

        super.init()
        self.title = title
    }
```

If you want to rename `coordiante` to `coords` for your readability purposes, I suggest to use an extension:

```swift
extension CustomPointAnnotation {
    var coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        get { return coordinate }
        set { coordinate = newValue }
    }
}
```

And assign it after `super.init()` just like title.

Comment: I simply ignored I could set title after the init

Answer (score 1):

You need to be setting `_title` in your initialiser instead of `title`. Since this is your own private backing property for `title`, when you access `title` for the first time, it will have the correct value without having to directly set it.

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {

    let eventID: Int
    let coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let location:String

    private var _title:String?

    override var title: String? {
        get { return _title }
        set { _title = newValue }
    }

    init(eventID:Int, coords:CLLocationCoordinate2D, location:String, title:String?) {

        self.eventID = eventID
        self.coords = coords
        self._title = title
        self.location = location

        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like I spent more time in writing the question than in writing the code   :-D